# Pattern match data from file in Lua

Tags: string, file-io, lua, pattern-matching

I've been tasked with creating a new server modification for Crysis Wars. I have ran into a particular issue that it cannot read the old ban-file (this is required in order to keep the server consistent). The Lua code itself does not seem to have any errors, but it's just not getting any of the data.
Looking at the code I'm using for this below, can you find anything wrong with it?

This is the code I'm using for this:

```
function rX.CheckBanlist(player)
    local Root = System.GetCVar("sys_root");
    local File = ""..Root.."System/Bansystem/Raptor.xml";
    local FileHnd = io.open(File, "r");
    for line in FileHnd:lines() do
        if (not string.find(line, "User:Read")) then
            System.Log("[rX] File Read Error: System/Raptor/Banfile.xml, The contents are unexpected.");
            return false;
        end
        local Msg, Date, Reason, Type, Domain = string.match(line, "User:Read( '(.*)', { Date='(.*)'; Reason='(.*)'; Typ='(.*)'; Info='(.*)'; } );");
        local rldomain = g_gameRules.game:GetDomain(player.id);
        if (Domain == rldomain) then
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        end
    end
end
```

Also, the actual file reads as this, but I can't get the " to work in Lua properly. Could this be the issue?

```
User:Read( "Banned", { Date="31.03.2011"; Reason="WEBSTREAM"; Typ="Inetnum"; Info="COMPUTER.SED.gg"; } );
```

Comment: Are you sure 'raptor.xml' is really an xml file and not a lua file? The file content seems to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may prefer using Lua's `[[` for multiline string when you want to include quotes inside quotes etc.

Also, you'd have to escape the `(` and `)` while matching:

```lua
local Msg, Date, Reason, Type, Domain = line:match([[User:Read%( "(.-)", { Date="(.+)"; Reason="(.+)"; Typ="(.+)"; Info="(.+)"; } %);]])
```

And the results will be as expected: http://codepad.org/gN8kSL6H